# Create subdomain on localhost and user dns

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, subdomain

My ISP is providing me a user dns like "user".ddns."providersite.com".
I made "img" subdomain on localhost. I`ve edited the win host file, adding

127.0.0.1  img.localhost

and I`ve added this to the apache virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName img.localhost
DocumentRoot "C:/www/web/img"
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm index.shtml
</VirtualHost>
```

So can I make ot work on the internet - img."user".ddns."providersite.com" ? Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might ask your ISP to put a wildcard subdomain on `"user".ddns.providersite.com` like `*.user.providersite.com`

But it completely depends on your provider to resolve the domain. If I remember it correctly there are other DDNS-providers which include this feature. A (german) provider which I remember is [Servermaster](http://dyndns.servermaster.de/). You might try looking there

Comment: Agreed.  You could always do this with your own domain, too.  You could create multiple CNAME records, all pointing back to your ISP-provided DNS name.